# Can't show TortoiseSVN overlays in windows explorer

Tags: tortoisesvn

I tried these methods, very weird, only file/directory in c: have this problem, other file/directory under d: are OK.

1. Cleanup > "Refresh Shell overlays"
2. Upgrade TortoiseSVN to latest version 1.7.7
3. Restart Windows
4. Tried method at http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2010/01/05/oh-no-my-tortoisesvn-overlays-are-missing.aspx

All methods are not work, any suggestion?

ANSWER:
Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Include Paths: 
  ==> added path here, and overlays work

Comment: What Windows version do you have?

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question, I mean by a real answer? So that it disappears from unanswered tab?

Comment: Agree with @VolkerE. You should answer the question and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Include Paths: ==> added path here, and overlays work